# Android Chat/Messaging application

Tags: android, android-studio, server, instant-messaging

i was hoping that you could help me. I am trying to create a messaging application for my college computing project and i don't know where to start. I'm not asking for help on coding the application, i'm asking for the main points of the messaging application so i can start on writing the algorithm. But i cant use firebase or anything like that as I need to code the server side as well and as i'm aware firebase doesn't let me do that. So, what i'm asking for is the main points to start coding the algorithm, and everything that i would need to do so. And if possible, if you could suggest any servers that i could host from my PC, that would be great. Thank you!

Also, will i have to use a database to find the friends that i am able to message?

Answer (score 0):

You can look this open source back-end services [wire-server](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-server).